# Combining quantum circuits in Qiskit

Tags: typeerror, qiskit

In Qiskit the instruction to add two quantum circuits

qc1 + qc2

produces the following error

"unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuantumCircuit' and 'QuantumCircuit'"

I'm guessing my library must be missing something but as I'm new to Qiskit and Python I'm not sure what?

I was expecting qc2 to be appended to qc1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` operator is no longer supported by QuantumCircuit. From [Qiskit Terra 0.23. release notes](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#release-notes-0-23-0-upgrade-notes) (Upgrade section).

> The QuantumCircuit methods combine and extend have been removed
> following their deprecation in Qiskit Terra 0.17.0. This was done
> because these functions were simply less powerful versions of
> QuantumCircuit.compose(), which should be used instead.
>
> The removal of extend also means that the + and += operators are no
> longer defined for QuantumCircuit. Instead, you can use the & and &=
> operators respectively, which use QuantumCircuit.compose().